# For a List<Long> in Java, do you have to cast primitive long into Long before adding it?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, casting

If you have `List<Long> list`, do you have to cast primitive longs to Long?

Do you have to do this

`long l = -1;
list.add( (Long) l);`

or will

`list.add(l);`

be fine and not cause any exceptions/errors?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: come-on surely it is quicker just to try than to ask SO?

Comment: If u need to know why we don't need to cast then read about auto-boxing and auto-unboxing.

Comment: you need to learn about primitives, Wrapper classes, auto boxing & unboxing in java.

Comment: I knew about wrapper classes, but I didn't know there was such a thing as autoboxing and unboxing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your java version is > 1.5 since you used generic list.

So in your case, `list.add(l);` will work

Don't be afraid to try such things on your local machine.

Read more here: [Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 0):

No you do not, the `int` primitives will be [AutoBoxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to cast primitive type `long` to object wrapper class `Long` compiler takes care of it. It is called Autoboxing.

As **JavaDoc** says : *Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.*. Please [refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Consider the following code:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 2)
    list.add(i);
```

Although you add the int values as primitive types, rather than Integer objects, to list, the code compiles. Because list is a list of Integer objects, not a list of int values, you may wonder why the Java compiler does not issue a compile-time error. The compiler does not generate an error because it creates an Integer object from i and adds the object to list. Thus, the compiler converts the previous code to the following at runtime:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 2)
    list.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
```